# GridView Orientation with Wrapping in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

I am developing a WinRT app in c# , I am using a GridView to present my item.

I want my items to be arranged Horizontally and then(when reached the max width) next items should be added to the new row(**Simply:** *only vertical scroll-bars can be visible*).

Unfortunately my current xaml can only add items horizontal in one row(with a horizontal scroll bar)

```
<GridView x:Name="GridChildItem" 
                  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NonTickGridViewItem}" 
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomChildItemTemplete}"
                  SelectionMode="Single" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                  ItemClick="gridViewChild_ItemClick_1"
                  Margin="0,40,0,0" 
                  Height="Auto"
                  Background="{StaticResource DropDownMenuBackColor}" 
                  ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False"
                  ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled ="True"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

           </GridView.ItemsPanel>
 </GridView>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `WrapGrid` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`? E.g. `<GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>           </GridView.ItemsPanel>`?

Comment: @nemesv . Yes but with no success

Comment: I don't have win8 at hand but you can also try to use `ListView` instead of the `GridView` with `WrapGrid` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`...

Comment: @nemesv, Thanks it is working well with listview and WrapGrid

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to allow horizontal scrolling you need to use `ListView` instead of `GridView`,

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx)

> Use a **ListView** to display a collection of data that scrolls
>   vertically. To display a collection that scrolls horizontally, use a
>   **GridView**.

But if you want to keep the wrapping behavior you need to use [WrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid) as the `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ListView>
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @vibeeshanRC yes did it without VS or win8, what do you want to know?

Comment: Nothing i am just appreciating you

Answer (score 10):

The default ItemsPanelTemplate of a GridView contains a WrapGrid with Orientation="Vertical": it stacks vertical and scrolls horizontal.

If you change the Orientation to Horizontal, it will stack horizontal, but for some reason won't scroll. You can solve that by setting ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ***on the GridView*** (not on the WrapGrid!).

Example:

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: This doesnt work. It just allows the grid view to bounce up and down when the user swipes it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not following all of this thread, but for me VS2013 win store app simply changing WrapGrid's Orientation="Horizontal" did the trick !

Comment: I'm testing under Win 8.1, and I also had to enable the scrollbar visibility of the GridView: `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"`  This could just be specific to my settings though.