# Different ItemsPanelTemplate in a GridView GroupStyle

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

In a Windows Store App I'm using groupped items in a GridView. I've created different data templates but I can not create different `ItemsPanelTemplate`s, because there is no selector for that. But my goal is:
Let's say I would like to create 2 groups. One of them should be `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as `ItemsPanelTemplate` and the code looks like this:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

It scrolls horizontally and wrap the items list by four.

The other one should be a vertical list, with vertical scrolling option. There are two problems here.

1. I don't know how to use **another** `ItemsPanelTemplate` because there is no selector.
2. The other problem is, when I use `VariableSizedWrapGrid` with `Orientation="Vertical"` it shows no scrolling option vertically, it just cuts off the list at the bottom of the screen.

Edit:
I've found a solution to the 2. question of mine here:
[Vertical scrolling inside GridView group of items in WinRT XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135480/vertical-scrolling-inside-gridview-group-of-items-in-winrt-xaml)
So now I can use vertically scrollable items but I would like to use horizontally in 1 group and vertically in the other one! So the 1. question is still on.

Comment: Windows Store `GridView` contains `ItemTemplateSelector` property and I use it in my project. One group shows the small items and another group shows the buig items (doubled height).

Comment: I use `ItemTemplateSelector` to give different look to the items. That is not what I need. I need to change the arrangment of the items, one group should be vertically scrollable and the other should be horizontally with wrapping. My question was about `ItemsPanelTemplate` and selector for that, not for `ItemTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

Can you bind the relevant properties to Dependency Properties or better still properties in your viewmodel then change appropriately.

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="{Binding MyOrientation}" 
        MaximumRowsOrColumns="{Binding MyMaxRows}"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Comment: This is useful, but if I bind `Orientation="Vertical"` to a group, it does not scroll horizontally. Do you know why? If I put a `ScrollViewer` around `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, it crashes.

The link I shared about the solution to my second question, plays with `GroupStyle.ContainerStyle` and I don't know how to put together that solution and yours. Could you help me a little more on that?

Comment: In a WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" will try and place each item below the last until it reaches your maximum rows =4 then it will move onto the next column to the right. Horizontal tries to place each new item to the right of the last until it reaches maxcolumn =4 then places the next one in the row below and repeats. ItemsPanleTemplate expects a Panel as a child so will crash if you put a scrollviewer in there. GridView has its own Scrollviewer for you to use eg <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ...etc hope that helps :)

Comment: My horizontal group will be wrapped, it's okay. But what if I would like to have that vertical group to contain so many item that is needs to be scrolled vertically and not to be wrapped. WrapGrid with wrap it anyway. What's the solution for that? In this case I need a ScrollViewer for a Group, not for the whole GridView.

Comment: Just seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190572/gridview-orientation-with-wrapping-in-winrt might be best to use ListView